# JSON validator validates the JSON but my left hand tags are not appearing

Tags: mysql, json

i am developing an iOS app and this app fetches data using JSON from mysql database. i have configured the json properly so far. right hand $outputs are ok and json validator validated the json formatting is completely ok. but my left hand tags are not appearing some how. here i m providing the code what i did. For this app publishing is on hold for long time.

```
//fetch data from current month table
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $monthyear where news_date = '$date'");

if (!$q) {
    die('Invalid query executed: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($e=mysql_fetch_row($q)){
    $output[]=$e;
 $responce[$e]['news_id'] = $output['news_id'];
 $responce[$e]['news_title'] = $output['news_title'];
 $responce[$e]['news_reporter'] = $output['news_reporter'];
 $responce[$e]['news_details'] = $output['news_details'];
 $responce[$e]['photo'] = $output['photo'];
 $responce[$e]['path'] = 'admin/'.str_replace('\\','',$output['path']);
 $responce[$e]['menu_id'] = $output['menu_id'];
 $responce[$e]['menu_type'] = $output['menu_type'];
 $responce[$e]['news_publish_status'] = $output['news_publish_status'];
 $responce[$e]['news_order'] = $output['news_order'];
 $responce[$e]['news_date'] = $output['news_date'];
 $responce[$e]['news_time'] = $output['news_time'];
 $responce[$e]['added_by'] = $output['added_by'];
 $responce[$e]['directory'] = $output['directory'];
 $responce[$e]['read_number'] = $output['read_number'];
 $responce[$e]['comment_number'] = $output['comment_number'];
 $responce[$e]['news_comment_table_name'] = $output['news_comment_table_name'];     
}
echo(json_encode($output));
```

I am not getting any way to show left hand tags though it exists in the script. can any one help me on this by guiding or giving an example from existing source code after modifications. TIA

Ishtiaque

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "left hand" or "right hand tags". Please clarify.

Comment: it is `echo(json_encode($output));` or  `echo(json_encode($responce));`?

Comment: The output supposed to be like this {"id":"1","name":"Ehtesham","roll_no":"131","degree":"BSCS"} but after = $output is returning data but $responce[$e]["comment_number"] aren't getting appeared for perfect data fetching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$e` which is an array as an array key in `$response[$e]`, and this is [not allowed in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.

I think you want to use the ID as a key.

Comment: @AMIshtiaqueSarwar Welcome to StackOverflow! The 'accept' checkmark to the left of the answer is the best way to say 'thank you'.